# color coded map based on population

Tags: json, d3.js, mapping, heatmap

Good day,

I am having trouble with the coloring in my svg. I created a simple map and i want to color the country based on their population...

here is my code..

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>World Population</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js">
       </script> 
        </head>
           <style>

              path {
               stroke:white;
               stroke-width: 1px;
               }

               body {
               font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
               }

             .country {
              font: 10px sans-serif;
              font-weight: bold;
              }

             .legend {
              font-size: 12px;
             }

             div.tooltip {   
            position: absolute;           
           text-align: center;           
           width: 150px;                  
           height: 25px;                 
          padding: 2px;             
           font-size: 10px;     
             background: #FFFFE0;
          border: 1px;      
           border-radius: 8px;           
           pointer-events: none;         
            }        
            </style>
              <body>
              <script type="text/javascript">
               var width = 960,
                height = 500;

      // Setting color domains(intervals of values) for our map

  var color_domain = [50, 150, 350, 750, 1500]
  var ext_color_domain = [0, 50, 150, 350, 750, 1500]
  var legend_labels = ["< 50", "50+", "150+", "350+", "750+", "> 1500"]
  var color = d3.scale.threshold()
  .domain(color_domain)
  .range(["#adfcad", "#ffcb40", "#ffba00", "#ff7d73", "#ff4e40", "#ff1300"]);

  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("margin", "10px auto");


  var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
   .center([0, 5])
   .scale(150)
   .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
   .rotate([0, 0])
   .precision(.9);

  //var projection = d3.geo.albers()
  //.rotate([-105, 0])
  //.center([-10, 65])
  //.parallels([52, 64])
  //.scale(700)
  //.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  //Reading map file and data

  queue()
  //    .defer(d3.json, "Script/topojson/examples/russia.json")
  .defer(d3.json, "Script/topojson/examples/world-110m.json")
  .defer(d3.csv, "data/accidents.csv")
  .await(ready);

  //Start of Choropleth drawing

  function ready(error, world, data) {
      var rateById = {};
      var nameById = {};

      data.forEach(function (d) {


          rateById[d.RegionCode] = +d.Deaths;
          nameById[d.RegionCode] = d.RegionName;
      });

      //Drawing Choropleth

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "path")
      .selectAll("path")

      .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", function (d) {
          return color(rateById[d.properties.RegionName]);
      })
      .style("opacity", 0.8)

      //Adding mouseevents
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          d3.select(this).transition().duration(300).style("opacity", 1);
          div.transition().duration(300)
          .style("opacity", 1)
          div.text(nameById[d.properties.countries] + " : " +  
                rateById[d.properties.countries])
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function () {
          d3.select(this)
          .transition().duration(300)
          .style("opacity", 0.8);
          div.transition().duration(300)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      })

      // Adding cities on the map

      d3.csv("data/s.csv", function (error, data) {
          var city = svg.selectAll("g.country")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "country")
          .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + projection([d.lon, d.lat]) + ")"; });

          city.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 3)
          .style("fill", "lime")
          .style("opacity", 0.75);

          city.append("text")
          .attr("x", 5)
          .text(function (d) { return d.countries; });
      });

  }; // <-- End of Choropleth drawing

  //Adding legend for our Choropleth

  var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
  .data(ext_color_domain)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");

  var ls_w = 20, ls_h = 20;

  legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", function (d, i) { return height - (i * ls_h) - 2 * ls_h; })
  .attr("width", ls_w)
  .attr("height", ls_h)
  .style("fill", function (d, i) { return color(d); })
  .style("opacity", 0.8);

  legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", function (d, i) { return height - (i * ls_h) - ls_h - 4; })
  .text(function (d, i) { return legend_labels[i]; });

        </script>
       </body>
        </html>
```

that's my whole code..

here is my data

```
      id,   RegionCode, RegionName,    Population   
      608,  PHL,        Philippines,   10500              
      124,  CAN,            Canada,        2540                    
      156,  CHN,            China,         95874
```

here is my other data

```
          country,lat,lon
           PHILIPPINES,13,122
           CANADA,60,-95             
           CHINA,35,105
```

the color must defend on the number of population of countries

i am having trouble with the foreach. undefined error

Comment: The error message would suggest that there's a problem loading the data. Did you verify that all the paths are correct and that the data is loaded?

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff  i think you're right. but i dont have idea on how could i know, if the data is being loaded on the page..is there a way how could i debug this script?just like visual studio, just to know is data is being loaded..one thing i know is that the data.foreach must be read. i dont think RegionCode must be also be in json file.

Comment: Printing the error would be a good start.

Comment: Is there any white space in the headers data?  That could be causing the undefined error.  Also the forEach seems to be looking for a column called Deaths not Population

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, yes. i also replace it with Population, thanks for that, i can view now the map on the page. but the choropleth doesnt seem to load, coz the color of mt svg is black.. is there any error regarding my code..

Comment: You may want to use one of the [colour scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category10) for setting the fill colour.

Comment: Do you want the rateIt object to link the RegionName to Population in the forEach.  If that's the case try this rateById[d.RegionName] = +d.Population;

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, i replace it with your suggestion, but nothing happens, my svg return black. i think there's no problem with the color it working. i hope you we can solve this..

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a complete working example somewhere (e.g. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Your code looks ok to me.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, i'll post it there..http://jsfiddle.net/cyberdaemon/2DJUp/       http://jsfiddle.net/cyberdaemon/2DJUp/embedded/result/                      <iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/cyberdaemon/2DJUp/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: We'll need the data as well -- without it, nothing will be displayed.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, I am sorry, i wasnt able to paste my data. i already paste it there. hope we can solve this one..

Comment: Well, as the other commenter pointed out, there are a few inconsistencies in your code. These might be the source of your problem, but they certainly prevent us from creating a working example with the data you've provided.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, i already run it using the JShint and fix does error..once i run the JSHint i already correct the error there and my code here..

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, i been working it now an i am facing new problem, it seems that it return only the color that is on the last list of the accidents.csv,can you point me out the right direction..

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff.. here is my new code http://jsfiddle.net/cyberdaemon/5kw2J/#&togetherjs=ThD7nNl2HJ

Comment: The code without the data (i.e. I can't run it) is not very helpful I'm afraid...

Comment: It looks like you would need `cId[d.id]` instead of `cId[d.Population]`.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff.. thanks you for the solution that you gave to me.. it works perfect.. thanks

Comment: Great, posted that as an answer for reference.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff... here is my newest code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a simple typo in the code. Instead of referencing `cId[d.Population]`, you need to refer to `cId[d.id]`.

Answer (score 0):

another one problem why is it the on my mouseover it return NAN for population?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
          <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Population - Choropleth</title>

<script src="Scripts/d3.v3.min.js" ></script>
<script src="Scripts/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8">                 </script>-->


     </head>
      <style>

      path {
        stroke:white;
        stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   }

       .city {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
      }

     .legend {
     font-size: 12px;
      }

     div.tooltip {   
      position: absolute;           
      text-align: center;           
     width: 200px;                  
    height: 80px;                 
        padding: 2px;             
     font-size: 10px;     
      background: #FFFFE0;
     border: 1px;      
      border-radius: 8px;           
        pointer-events: none;  
      font-family:'Courier New';
      font-size:medium;      
 }        
  </style>
       <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var width = 900,
        height = 400;

  // Setting color domains(intervals of values) for our map

  var color_domain = [50, 150, 350, 750, 1500];
  var ext_color_domain = [0, 50, 150, 350, 750, 1500];
  var legend_labels = ["< 50", "50+", "150+", "350+", "750+", "> 1500"];
  var color = d3.scale.log()
  .domain(color_domain)
  .range(["#adfcad", "#ffcb40", "#ffba00", "#ff7d73", "#ff4e40", "#ff1300"]);

  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("margin", "10px auto");

  var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
  .center([0, 5])
    .scale(150)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .rotate([0, 0])
    .precision(9);


  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  //Reading map file and data

  queue()

  .defer(d3.json, "Scripts/topojson/examples/world-110m.json")
  .defer(d3.csv, "data/accidents.csv")
  .await(ready);

  //Start of Choropleth drawing

  function ready(error, map, data) {
      var cId = {};
      var nameById = {};




      data.forEach(function (d) {
          cId[d.id] = +d.Population;
          nameById[d.id] = d.RegionName;

          //console.log(data);

      });

      // 
      //Drawing Choropleth
      svg.append("g")

      .attr("class", "region")
      .selectAll("path")
      //.data(topojson.object(map, map.objects.russia).geometries)

      .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.countries).features)
     .enter()
      .append("path")
     .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", function (d) {
          return color(cId[d.id]);


      })
      //.style("opacity", 0.8)

      //Adding mouseevents
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          d3.select(this)
          .transition()
         .duration(300)
         .style("opacity", 1);
          div.transition()
          .duration(300)
          .style("opacity", 1)

          // div.text(nameById[d.id])//+""+cId[d.Population] // + " " + cid[d.Population])
          div.text("Country Name :" + nameById[d.id] + "' <br />'" + "Population :" + cId[d.Population])
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function () {
          d3.select(this)
          .transition().duration(300)
          .style("opacity", 0.8);
          div.transition().duration(300)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      })

      // Adding cities on the map

      //d3.tsv("cities.tsv", function (error, data) {
      d3.csv("data/s.csv", function (error, data) {


          var city = svg.selectAll("g.city")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("class", "city")
          .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + projection([d.lon, d.lat]) + ")"; });
          console.log(data)
          city.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 3)
          .style("fill", "lime")
          .style("opacity", 0.75);

          city.append("text")
          .attr("x", 5)
          .text(function (d) { return d.countries; });


      });

  }; // <-- End of Choropleth drawing

  //Adding legend for our Choropleth

  var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
  .data(ext_color_domain)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");

  var ls_w = 20, ls_h = 20;

  legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", function (d, i) { return height - (i * ls_h) - 2 * ls_h; })
  .attr("width", ls_w)
  .attr("height", ls_h)
  .style("fill", function (d, i) { return color(d); })
  .style("opacity", 0.8);

  legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", function (d, i) { return height - (i * ls_h) - ls_h - 4; })
  .text(function (d, i) { return legend_labels[i]; });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the HTML code like that:

```
<table data-i2="css:[{color:'#888888'},{color:'#000000'}]">
    <tr data-i2="rate:1500">
        <td>Philippines</td>
        <td>1500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-i2="rate:2540">
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>2540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-i2="rate:95874">
        <td>China</td>
        <td>95874</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then call [i2ui](http://i2ui.com) method: i2.emph().

See demo - http://jsfiddle.net/AMjP9/.